# d3 Draw Only Map Features in Zoomed Bounding Box

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I've built a map where on hover over of a certain (x,y) coordinate point, a zoomed in mini-map shows up to the side with the hovered point in the center (using code similar to: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590). It works well, but a bit inefficient because it is redrawing the whole map with a new scale and translate every time which I noticed when I took off overflow: hidden from the mini-map in IE.

Is there a built-in way in d3 or TopoJSON to filter map features to only keep those that fall within the bounding box of the zoomed in area?

Thanks!

Comment: You can filter the feature array as in selection.filter(function (d) { return stuff; }).  Is that what you're after?

Comment: I'm familiar with that feature, but I didn't know if there was an easy way to only return features that fall into my desired bounding box.

Comment: If you've got the coordinates of the bounding box wouldn't that work? Maybe not too easy though ...